# Can't convert div to pdf inside ui:composition and ui:define

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to convert an xhtml file to a pdf
that's done with success using a simple html file

but, I can't do it when integrating `<ui:composition template="/template/index1.xhtml">` and `<ui:define name="pageContent">`

like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head>
    <title>JSF2 - download PDF after button click</title>

    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-c9vxcXyAG4paArQG3xk6DjyW/9aHxai2ef9RpMWO44A="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
</h:head>



<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/template/index1.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="pageContent">
            <div id="content2"
                style="background: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;">
                SARIA</div>

            <button class="btn btn-info" id="downloadPDF">Download PDF</button>
            <script>
                $('#downloadPDF').click(
                        function() {
                            domtoimage.toPng(
                                    document.getElementById('content2')).then(
                                    function(blob) {
                                        var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [
                                                $('#content2').width(),
                                                $('#content2').height() ]);

                                        pdf.addImage(blob, 'PNG', 0, 0, $(
                                                '#content2').width(), $(
                                                '#content2').height());
                                        pdf.save("test.pdf");

                                        that.options.api.optionsChanged();
                                    });
                        });
            </script>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Could you please tell me what I missed ?. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try that code:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest();

        try
        {
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

            SharedContext scontext=renderer.getSharedContext();
            scontext.setDotsPerPixel(14);
            renderer.setDocument(url);

            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);

            renderer.layout();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ec.getResponse();
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""+ fileName + ".pdf\"");
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            renderer.createPDF(os);
            os.close(); 

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        fc.responseComplete();
```

and

```
<p:commandButton value="Print" action="#{manageBean.createPDFOfSurveyResult()}" ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target='_blank'"/>
```

Hope To Help